# Compute math in every element of the list

Tags: python

This is my list

```
[0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.72, 0.73, 0.76, 0.77, 0.8, 0.78, 0.85,
 0.8, 0.84, 0.84, 0.85, 0.82, 0.86, 0.84, 0.85, 0.84, 0.83, 0.84, 0.86, 0.87, 
 0.88, 0.87, 0.88, 0.87, 0.88, 0.88, 0.88, 0.88, 0.89, 0.89, 0.88, 0.88, 0.9, 
 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.9, 0.89, 0.9, 0.89, 0.91, 0.88, 0.9, 0.88, 0.94, 0.87]
```

if I want every element to be `1 - list[i]`,  for example
`newlist = [0.3,0.3,0.3,...]`. How to do this in Python?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you mean a `list` comprehension:

```
lst = [0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.72, 0.73, 0.76, 0.77, 0.8, 0.78, 0.85, 0.8, 0.84, 0.84, 0.85, 0.82, 0.86, 0.84, 0.85, 0.84, 0.83, 0.84, 0.86, 0.87, 0.88, 0.87, 0.88, 0.87, 0.88, 0.88, 0.88, 0.88, 0.89, 0.89, 0.88, 0.88, 0.9, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.9, 0.89, 0.9, 0.89, 0.91, 0.88, 0.9, 0.88, 0.94, 0.87]
print([1 - i for i in lst])
```

Or use `map`:

```
print(list(map(1..__sub__, lst)))
```

Comment: or you can use numpy

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension is a way to create new lists:

```
new_list = [1-x for x in old_list]
```

[expression to evaluate for each element of the starting "collection"]

Python guide:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: it is a good practice to advocate your solution.